# Valgrind blocks are lost

Tags: c

I'm trying to write the data structure stack in C. Each element of my stack is a string. Below are the three files that I used. The first one is a main the other ones are the header stack.h and the file stack.c. I declared stackElement as a pointer to the element. stackT is a struct that define a stack. My problem appears when I trying to free allocate memory, because when I run valgrind I get

```
==31235== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==31235== 
==31235== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:
==31235== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==31235==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31235==    by 0x400893: StackDestroy (in /test)
==31235==    by 0x400B61: main (in /test)
==31235==  Address 0x51fc150 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==31235==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31235==    by 0x400B55: main (in /test)

24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
```

Could you help me please?

```
int main(){
stackT S;
int r = 3, i;
StackInit(&S, 2, r);
printf("test\n");
stackElementT s0;
s0 = malloc((r + 1) * sizeof(unsigned char));
memset(s0, 1, r + 1);
s0[r] = 0;
for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    s0[i] = random() & 0xff;
}
StackPush(&S, s0);
free(s0);
StackDestroy(&S);
return 0;
}
```

stack.h

```
typedef unsigned char * stackElementT;
typedef struct {
  stackElementT *contents;
  int maxSize;
  int top;
} stackT;
```

stack.c

```
void StackInit(stackT *stackP, int maxSize, int r) {
stackElementT *newContents;
int i;
r = 3;
newContents = malloc(sizeof(stackElementT) * maxSize);

if (newContents == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient memory to initialize stack.\n");
        exit(1); 
}

for (i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
    if ((newContents[i] = malloc(r * sizeof(stackElementT))) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient memory to initialize stack.\n");
        exit(1); 
    }
}

stackP->contents = newContents;
stackP->maxSize = maxSize;
stackP->top = -1; /* I.e., empty */
}

void StackDestroy(stackT *stackP) {
int i;
for (i = 0; i < stackP->maxSize; i++)
    free(stackP->contents[i]);
free(stackP->contents);
stackP->contents = NULL;
stackP->maxSize = 0;
stackP->top = -1; 
}
void StackPush(stackT *stackP, stackElementT element) {
if (StackIsFull(stackP)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't push element on stack: stack is full.\n");
    exit(1); 
}
stackP->contents[++stackP->top] = element;
}
```

EDIT:

Using the answers below I comment the line free(s0), but I get the next error now:

```
==31855== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==31855==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31855==    by 0x4007F9: StackInit (in /test)
==31855==    by 0x400AA9: main (in /test)
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < stackP->maxSize; i++) free(stackP->contents[i]);` This tries to free empty stack slots.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Why his tries to free empty stack slots?

Comment: Try adding the `--track-origins=yes` flag to valgrind, it should show you where the memory was allocated, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first valgrind message is pretty clear: you're freeing the same block of memory twice, first with `free(s0)` in `main` and for the second time in `StackDestroy`. Chang your code so it doesn't do that - either by having the stack take ownership of the objects (so it frees them and `main` doesn't), or vice-versa (the stack does not take ownership of the objects and does not free them).

The "blocks lost" matter is because you allocate blocks of memory for each stack slot in the loop in `StackInit`, and `StackPush` overwrites the pointers so you can never release the original memory allocated for used stack slots. There are at least two possible resolutions here as well: don't pre-allocate blocks of memory in `StackInit` (just copy pointers in `StackPush`), or copy the element *data* (instead of the pointer) in `StackPush`.

Comment: when I comment "free(s0);" now I get only one error but error yet. The error is 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1

Comment: oks I choose the second option, then I change stackP->contents[++stackP->top] = element; by memcpy(stackP->contents[++stackP->top],element,r); but I get  4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==32064==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32064==    by 0x400B70: main (in /test)

Comment: Since you've changed `StackPush` to copy the data (and not take ownership of the pointer), you need to free the malloced `s0` block in `main` again.

Answer (score 0):

You free s0 in `StackDestroy()` and in `main()`.

Comment: when I comment "free(s0);" now I get only one error but error yet. The error is 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1.